# How to get the name the parent directory of the current directory within a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, directory, compilation

Suppose I have `Makefile` in `/myPDir/myCurrDir`. Inside a `Makefile` I can retrieve the name of the current directory as:

```
CURR_DIR_NAME  := $(notdir $(CURDIR))
$(warning CURR_DIR_NAME IS $(CURR_DIR_NAME))
```

or

```
CURR_DIR_NAME  := $(shell basename $(CURDIR))
$(warning CURR_DIR_NAME IS $(CURR_DIR_NAME))
```

and the second line in both cases will print `myCurrDir`.

Now I want to obtain the name of the parent directory, i.e. `myPDir`. I tried to use instead of `$(CURDIR)`, `$(CURDIR)/..` but it does not work and prints `...`.

How can I refer the name of the parent directory, i.e. get the string `myCurrDir` in the example, as a variable in a `Makefile`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using `$(abspath $(<whatever>)/..)`

Commands like `notdir` or the shell's `basedir` are simple text string parsers.  So if you say `basename foo/..` it just returns the `..` since that's the last element on the path.

If you want the parent directory there are various ways to do it.  One simple way is to use the make `abspath` function to convert the relative path to an absolute path: `$(abspath /foo/bar/biz/..)` will return `/foo/bar`.  So, you can use:

```
PARENT = $(notdir $(abspath $(CURDIR)/..))
```